# Cannot read Package name from manifest.xml

Tags: java, android, debugging, manifest

[image]   Here is my android manifest file.I am new to development so sorry in advacne for poor indent and code.
The app is in the directory to D:\App\Managebale.The error came when i tried changing the name of the package to something other.Need a guidance here and thanks in Advance.The App I am trying to debug is open source and goes by the name of Omni Notes on github.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="it.feio.android.omninotes">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.apps.photos.permission.GOOGLE_PHOTOS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.pushbullet.android.permission.READ_MESSAGING_EXTENSION_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.pushbullet.android.permission.SEND_MESSAGES" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.OmniNotes"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/OmniNotesTheme.ApiSpec.Branded"
    tools:replace="android:theme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".ListActivity" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        tools:replace="android:value" />

    <!-- List and Detail -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gm.action.AUTO_SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="hashtag" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <!-- Gallery -->
    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.GalleryActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/OmniNotesFullscreenTheme.ApiSpec" />

    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.CategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_category"
        android:parentActivityName="it.feio.android.omninotes.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- Settings -->
    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/settings"
        android:parentActivityName="it.feio.android.omninotes.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- Password -->
    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.PasswordActivity"
        android:theme="@style/OmniNotesTheme.ApiSpec.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

    <!-- Info -->
    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.AboutActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />

    <!-- Intro -->
    <activity
        android:name=".intro.IntroActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme" />

    <!-- Snooze reminder -->
    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.SnoozeActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/OmniNotesTheme.NoDisplay" />

    <!-- Home launcher shortcut -->
    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.ShortcutActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/shortcut_icon"
        android:label="@string/add_note">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Stats -->
    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.StatsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.NoteInfosActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />

    <!-- Alarm broadcast receiver -->
    <receiver android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.receiver.AlarmReceiver" />

    <!-- Reboot broadcast receiver -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.BootCompleteReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="BootCompleteReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Restore on reboot alarm service -->
    <service
        android:name=".async.AlarmRestoreOnRebootService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>

    <!-- Notification listener service -->
    <service
        android:name=".services.NotificationListener"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- Data export and import service -->
    <service android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.async.DataBackupIntentService" />

    <!-- Widget configuration Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.widget.WidgetConfigurationActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Widget Simple -->
    <receiver
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.widget.SimpleWidgetProvider"
        android:description="@string/widget_simple_description"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/appwidget_simple" />
    </receiver>
    <!-- Widget List -->
    <receiver
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.widget.ListWidgetProvider"
        android:description="@string/widget_list_description"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/appwidget_list" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.widget.ListWidgetService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

    <!-- DashClock plugin service -->
    <service
        android:name=".extensions.ONDashClockExtension"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_stat_literal_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.permission.READ_EXTENSION_DATA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.Extension" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="protocolVersion"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="worldReadable"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="description"
            android:value="@string/dashclock_description" />
        <!-- A settings activity is optional -->
        <!-- <meta-data -->
        <!-- android:name="settingsActivity" -->
        <!-- android:value=".ExampleSettingsActivity" /> -->
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="it.feio.android.omninotes.extensions.PushBulletExtension"
        android:permission="com.pushbullet.android.permission.READ_MESSAGING_EXTENSION_DATA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.pushbullet.android.extension.MessagingExtension" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="protocolVersion"
            android:value="1" />
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.authority"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

Comment: can you show me the folder structure that you have followed? just to check a doubt that i had got which might solve your problem

Comment: @SubhasmithThapa added file stucture